# How can I filter out undefined from string

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm fetching some data from an API and returning the response as text. Then I'm passing the result to another function where I want to format that data to get an JSON Object, but I always get undefined when I want to trim the data. When I do `indexOf(undefined)` it returns index -1.  Here is an example of the data:

> ,result,table,_start,_stop,_time,_value,Wizard,_field,_measurement,botName,errorLevel,errorLeveldescription,pcName,status,stepNr
> ,mean,0,2021-03-19T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-18T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-15T07:02:30Z,1,IPA_BOT,value,ipaMeasurement,IPA_BOT_1,400,INFO,SCHWCL07347,OK,1
> ,mean,0,2021-03-19T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-18T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-15T07:03:40Z,1,IPA_BOT,value,ipaMeasurement,IPA_BOT_1,400,INFO,SCHWCL07347,OK,1
> ,mean,0,2021-03-19T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-18T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-15T08:27:00Z,1,IPA_BOT,value,ipaMeasurement,IPA_BOT_1,400,INFO,SCHWCL07347,OK,1
> ,mean,0,2021-03-19T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-18T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-15T08:28:30Z,1,IPA_BOT,value,ipaMeasurement,IPA_BOT_1,400,INFO,SCHWCL07347,OK,1
> ,mean,0,2021-03-19T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-18T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-15T08:28:45Z,1,IPA_BOT,value,ipaMeasurement,IPA_BOT_1,400,INFO,SCHWCL07347,OK,1
> ,mean,0,2021-03-19T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-18T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-15T08:29:20Z,2,IPA_BOT,value,ipaMeasurement,IPA_BOT_1,400,INFO,SCHWCL07347,OK,1
> ,mean,0,2021-03-19T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-18T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-15T08:35:40Z,2,IPA_BOT,value,ipaMeasurement,IPA_BOT_1,400,INFO,SCHWCL07347,OK,1
> ,mean,0,2021-03-19T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-18T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-15T09:43:40Z,4,IPA_BOT,value,ipaMeasurement,IPA_BOT_1,400,INFO,SCHWCL07347,OK,1
> ,mean,0,2021-03-19T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-18T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-15T09:45:05Z,5,IPA_BOT,value,ipaMeasurement,IPA_BOT_1,400,INFO,SCHWCL07347,OK,1
> ,mean,0,2021-03-19T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-18T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-15T09:51:10Z,5,IPA_BOT,value,ipaMeasurement,IPA_BOT_1,400,INFO,SCHWCL07347,OK,1
> ,mean,1,2021-03-19T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-18T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-15T08:35:45Z,2,IPA_BOT,value,ipaMeasurement,IPA_BOT_1,400,INFO,SCHWCL07347,OK,2
> ,mean,1,2021-03-19T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-18T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-15T09:43:45Z,4,IPA_BOT,value,ipaMeasurement,IPA_BOT_1,400,INFO,SCHWCL07347,OK,2
> ,mean,1,2021-03-19T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-18T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-15T09:45:10Z,5,IPA_BOT,value,ipaMeasurement,IPA_BOT_1,400,INFO,SCHWCL07347,OK,2
> ,mean,1,2021-03-19T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-18T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-15T09:51:10Z,5,IPA_BOT,value,ipaMeasurement,IPA_BOT_1,400,INFO,SCHWCL07347,OK,2
> ,mean,2,2021-03-19T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-18T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-15T08:35:50Z,2,IPA_BOT,value,ipaMeasurement,IPA_BOT_1,400,INFO,SCHWCL07347,OK,3
> ,mean,2,2021-03-19T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-18T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-15T09:43:45Z,4,IPA_BOT,value,ipaMeasurement,IPA_BOT_1,400,INFO,SCHWCL07347,OK,3
> ,mean,2,2021-03-19T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-18T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-15T09:45:10Z,5,IPA_BOT,value,ipaMeasurement,IPA_BOT_1,400,INFO,SCHWCL07347,OK,3
> ,mean,2,2021-03-19T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-18T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-15T09:51:15Z,5,IPA_BOT,value,ipaMeasurement,IPA_BOT_1,400,INFO,SCHWCL07347,OK,3
> ,mean,3,2021-03-19T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-18T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-15T08:35:55Z,2,IPA_BOT,value,ipaMeasurement,IPA_BOT_1,400,INFO,SCHWCL07347,OK,4
> ,mean,3,2021-03-19T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-18T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-15T09:43:50Z,4,IPA_BOT,value,ipaMeasurement,IPA_BOT_1,400,INFO,SCHWCL07347,OK,4
> ,mean,3,2021-03-19T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-18T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-15T09:45:15Z,5,IPA_BOT,value,ipaMeasurement,IPA_BOT_1,400,INFO,SCHWCL07347,OK,4
> ,mean,3,2021-03-19T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-18T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-15T09:51:15Z,5,IPA_BOT,value,ipaMeasurement,IPA_BOT_1,400,INFO,SCHWCL07347,OK,4
> ,mean,4,2021-03-19T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-18T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-15T08:36:00Z,2,IPA_BOT,value,ipaMeasurement,IPA_BOT_1,400,INFO,SCHWCL07347,OK,5
> ,mean,4,2021-03-19T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-18T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-15T09:43:50Z,4,IPA_BOT,value,ipaMeasurement,IPA_BOT_1,400,INFO,SCHWCL07347,OK,5
> ,mean,4,2021-03-19T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-18T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-15T09:45:15Z,5,IPA_BOT,value,ipaMeasurement,IPA_BOT_1,400,INFO,SCHWCL07347,OK,5
> ,mean,4,2021-03-19T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-18T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-15T09:51:20Z,5,IPA_BOT,value,ipaMeasurement,IPA_BOT_1,400,INFO,SCHWCL07347,OK,5
> ,mean,5,2021-03-19T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-18T19:33:44.870040506Z,2021-04-15T08:38:10Z,2,IPA_BOT,value,ipaMeasurement,RestartMachine,400,INFO,SCHWCL07347,OK,7

```
export function get_influx_data() {
    let url = "api/url";
    let myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/vnd.flux");
    myHeaders.append("Accept", "application/csv");
    myHeaders.append(
        "Authorization",
        " api Token"
    );

    let raw =
        'api query body';
    let requestOptions = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: myHeaders,
        body: raw,
        redirect: "follow",
    };
    return fetch(url, requestOptions)
        .then(function (response) {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.text();
            } else {
                return Promise.reject(response)
            }
        }).then(function (result) {
            return result
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log("error: " + error)
        })
};
```

```
export function clean_influx_data(result) {
  var data = result.trim();
  var lines = data.split("\n");
  var result = [];

  var headers = lines[0].split(",");
  for (var i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
    if (!lines[i]) {
      continue;
    }
    var obj = {};
    var currentline = lines[i].split(",");

    for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
      obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
    }
    result.push(obj);
  }
  var rawJsonData = JSON.stringify(result);
  const parsedData = JSON.parse(rawJsonData);
```

```
import { get_influx_data } from './api.js'
import {clean_influx_data} from './clean_data.js'

var a = get_influx_data();
a.then((result) => clean_influx_data(result))
var b = clean_influx_data()
```

Comment: You can't return data from this callback: `.then(function (result) {return result})`

Comment: How can y return the data then?

Comment: You can use `await` instead of `.then`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

Comment: Do you mean in the fetch function or in the imports?

Comment: when i include the await in the a.then((result) => clean_influx_data(result)) so that it is a.await(result) => clean_influx_data(result)) i get the influx_query.await is not a function and Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: fetch(...).then(...).await is not a function errors

Comment: Forget my comments, I wasnt reading the code properly. I responded down below.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Promise.resolve(result).

```
return fetch(url, requestOptions)
        .then(function (response) {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.text();
            } else {
                return Promise.reject(response)
            }
        }).then(function (result) {
            return Promise.resolve(result);
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log("error: " + error)
        })
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but i still get the uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined in the var data = result.trim(); line

Comment: Have u debugged the code to see why it is undefined?

Comment: It says __proto__: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "pending"
[[PromiseResult]]: undefined

Comment: then result inside the Promise.resolve(result) must be undefined in the first place. You could also check, if result is defined before calling clean_influx_data

Comment: I now modified the index2.js so it looks like this: import { get_influx_data } from './api.js'
import {clean_influx_data} from './clean_data.js'

const influx_query = get_influx_data()
var clean_data = influx_query.then((response)=>clean_influx_data(response))
console.log(clean_data)  Added the Promise.resolve(result) and i dont get the error anymore. But how can i access now the return from the clean_influx_data function ? I also added the return result; to the clean_influx_data function because i dont need  var rawJsonData = JSON.stringify(result);constparsedDataJSON.parse(rawJsonData);